# Python metaprogramming update class A every time class B changes

Tags: python, metaprogramming

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 4

class C1(Base):
    ...

class C2(Base):
    ...

obj1 = C1()
obj2 = C2()

obj1.x = 2
```

I understand with "Singletons" if I change "self.x" of C1 it could automatically update "self.x" of every instance of that single class... but how would I update all classes using the same base?

Comment: If you use singletons in python you are usually doing something wrong.

Comment: You're after some form of "static" variable on the class:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone correct me if i'm wrong but this can be solved easily with a reaaaal simple descriptor so for example:

```
class KeepSync(object):
    def __init__(self, default):
        self.value = default
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value

class Foo(object):
    bar = KeepSync(0) 

class C1(Foo):
    pass

class C2(Foo):
    pass



f = C1()
g = C2()

print "f.bar is %s\ng.bar is %s" % (f.bar, g.bar)
print "Setting f.bar to 10"
f.bar = 10
print "f.bar is %s\ng.bar is %s" % (f.bar, g.bar)  # YAY BOTH ARE 10 !
```

Any object that inherits KeepSync descriptor will always return that value, i'm not sure if I helped but, that's how I understood the problem, you wouldn't even need a base class but you can

Answer (score 1):

Move the x declaration out of the init:

```
class Base:
    x = 4

    def __init__(self):
```

Later when you need to set it, do the following:

```
Base.x = 5
```

You could wrap this into a `@staticmethod` to make it easier as well.

As others have mentioned, static variables are *really* bad and you shouldn't use them unless it's your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work. While the initial `x = 4` is stored on the class, not the instance, any assignment such as `obj1.x = 2` will store it on the instance.

If you really want to create a singleton, (ab)use a metaclass to ensure that each instance created is actually the same one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/298479) for an example how to do it.

Comment: The problem with this example is that it only updates all instances of the same class. it wouldn't update obj2 when I change "self.x" in obj1

Comment: This is the "singleton" that I was referring to in my original post.

Comment: Oh, you want it to ignore inheritance. Should be easy to update the metaclass to use the base class as the key for the `_instances` dict instead of the actual class.